# Incorrect sort order

Tags: tablesorter

I am using the tablesorter on a basic table. 2 table headers, the first column is ordering the following items as follows:

```
000
00
0
000
00
0
1
2
3
etc.
```

With other data, it is being sorted as:

```
0
1
10
11
12
2
```

I have tried adding the class to each th of "sorter-digits" and it made no difference. Also configured tablesorter with:

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter({
     sortList: [[1,0]],
     headers: {
          0: { sorter: "digit" }
          1: { sorter: "digit" }
       }
});
```

...but again, am getting the above results. Feels like i'm missing something obvious?

Comment: It works for me - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1821/) - try setting the `debug` option to `true` and see if the correct column is being set to use a "digit" parser.

Comment: Still getting the incorrect order. I've added a fiddle to show:
http://jsfiddle.net/tho9uqk0/

To be clear: the required sort list should be:
000
000
00
0
1
2
3
10
11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the original tablesorter (v2.0.5b), then you can use a custom parser. This parser isn't ideal since it gives the zeroes a negative decimal value to maintain your desired sort order. It shouldn't be a problem if your data does not include any negative numbers - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/tho9uqk0/1/).

```
$(function() {

  $.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'zeros',
    is: function() {
      return false;
    },
    format: function(s, table) {
      var number = parseFloat(s);
      if (number === 0) {
        // add a negative decimal place to maintain sorting
        // using "5" assuming the max zero length is 5 ("00000")
        number = -1/(5 - s.length);
      }
      return number;
    },
    type: 'number'
  });

  $('table').tablesorter({
    headers: {
      0: { sorter: 'zeros' }
    }
  });

});
```

If you are using my [fork of tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), then you can add a custom [`textSorter`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#textsorter) to specifically handle zeros with different lengths - [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/sgjawqcy/).

```
$(function() {

  $('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    textSorter: {
      0: function(a, b, direction, columnIndex, table) {
        x = parseFloat(a);
        y = parseFloat(b);
        return x === 0 && y === 0 ?
            b.length - a.length : x - y;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

---

Update: For mixed content, instead of returning `x - y`, use the built-in `sortNatural` function - [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/sgjawqcy/1/)

```
$(function() {

  $('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    textSorter: {
      0: function(a, b) {
        x = parseFloat(a);
        y = parseFloat(b);
        return x === 0 && y === 0 ?
          b.length - a.length :
          $.tablesorter.sortNatural(a, b);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I am indeed using your (excellent) fork. Yes that's working great on the fiddle, but i think on my site it is choking because the list can also have mixed values in the list too, such as "all", and digit/character combos like "0.5L". So parseFloat may not be the right function here.

Comment: ahh i was looking through the docs for natural sorting. Works perfectly. Thanks for the quick support :)